# Регистрация DLL

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

Есть .Net проект при компиляции которого получается Dll библиотека.

И есть множество других проектов которые используют эту библиотеку.

Проблема в том, чтобы поддерживать актуальную версионность данной библиотеки во всех проектах. Сложно отследить где какая dll-ка используется (из Дебага или Релиза) + путь до Dll-ки периодически меняется (проект библиотеки и использующие его проекты лежат в SVN и при загрузке на другой ПК все ссылки на библиотеку приходится обновлять)

Хочется, чтобы после компиляции Dll библиотеки она регистрировалась в системе или каким-либо другим образом становилась доступной для подключения через менеджер ссылок VisualStudio (Проект->добавить ссылку)

Установка галочки напротив "Регистрация для COM взаимодействия" (Свойства проекта->Сборка) на 50% решает проблему. Dll добавляется в список библиотек на вкладке COM в менеджере ссылок. Но при попытке добавить библиотеку к проекту выдаёт эксепшн.

Вопрос: Как автоматически регистрировать dll библиотеку после каждой сборки?

PS: Полагаю, что добиться желаемого можно описав студии что нужно делать после успешной компиляции (свойства проекта->события сборки) но как и что там писать чтобы добиться желаемого я не знаю, и даже не соображу как корректно сформулировать вопрос гуглу.

Comment: _"чтобы после компиляции Dll библиотеки она регистрировалась в системе"_ -- dll (.net-сборку) можно зарегистрировать в GAC.

Comment: @Stack: Разобрался с регистрацией и автоматизацией этого процесса при сборке. Но чтобы добавить ссылку на данную библиотеку приходится лезть в Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL. Варианта добавить зарегистрированную библиотеку в один из каталогов менеджера ссылок не вариант?

Comment: для установки сборки в GAC есть gacutil -- добавил в ответ.

Comment: @Stack: Как регистировать сборки с помощью gacutil.exe я уже разобрался. Собственно об этом и написал выше. Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL это то место, куда попадает регистрируемая через gacutil.exe сборка.

Comment: если сборка в GAC, то полный путь к сборке указывать не нужно.

Comment: @Stack: Здорово. И как тогда подключать сборку из GAC к .NET проекту в  VS?

Comment: после установки сборки в GAC, в Visual Studio - Reference Manager сборка у вас не видна?

Comment: Visual Studio - Reference Manager нет. Но если спросить о наличии данной сборки у gacutil то он её успешно находит в числе зарегистрированных

Comment: см. [How to display an assembly in the "Add Reference" dialog box](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306149)

Comment: @Stack: Добавил запись в реестр следуя рекомендациям по преведённой вами ссылке. В итоге получилось так: http://itmages.ru/image/view/3335025/c2cd2dd7 
Но в Reference Manager либы по прежнему нет. Студию перезагружал.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для совместного использования сборки в нескольких приложениях, ее можно поместить в глобальный кэш сборок (GAC).
Для регистрации сборки в GAC используется утилита [Gacutil.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx) (Global Assembly Cache Tool).
В MSDN см. ["Работа со сборками и глобальным кэшем сборок"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/6axd4fx6(v=vs.110).aspx).

Для того чтобы сборка после установки в GAC стала видна в Visual Studion - Reference Manager , надо добавить запись в системный реестр

```
[HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\AssemblyFolders\MyAssemblies]    
   @="C:\\MyAssemblies"
```

Подробнее см. MSDN: [How to display an assembly in the "Add Reference" dialog box](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306149).